# DSGET outputs only few results

Tags: powershell, dns, windows-server-2008, domaincontroller

We have about 500 Users and we need to get a complete list of them, including service and administrator accounts.

DSQUERY from the following example will return all users but DSGET returns only about 10 results.

```
dsquery user -limit 0 | dsget user
```

Any ideas why this is happening and how to get all the output from DSQUERY to be processed through DSGET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used dsquery but getting a list of all user accounts in AD is very easy with powershell. Just change the properties list to suit your requirements:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties SamAccountName,HomeDrive,HomeDirectory,DistinguishedName
```

You can save the output to csv also:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties SamAccountName,HomeDrive,HomeDirectory,DistinguishedName | Export-Csv "C:\folder\adusers.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

---

**EDIT**: To only export specific properties you just need to select them before exporting to CSV:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties SamAccountName,HomeDrive,HomeDirectory,DistinguishedName | Select SamAccountName,HomeDrive,HomeDirectory,DistinguishedName | Export-Csv "C:\folder\adusers.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

...or a slightly neater way:

```
$Properties = "SamAccountName,HomeDrive,HomeDirectory,DistinguishedName"
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties $Properties | Select $Properties | Export-Csv "C:\folder\adusers.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thank you for great help. Follow up Question: When saving to .csv the chosen properties are neglected and simply all properties are shown. Is there any way to pre-filter the properties exported to the .csv?

Comment: You just need to select the properties before exporting to csv, I'll update my answer to show it..

Comment: Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

think that this is happened because your user have spaces in CN
example
`dsquery user -samid saa | dsget user -samid`
not work
`dsquery user -samid saa`
return
"CN=Jhon DOU,OU=someou,DC=somedc,DC=anotherdc"
if we will type in another way
`dsget user "CN=Jhon DOU,OU=someou,DC=somedc,DC=anotherdc" -dn`
all will be ok for this case

agree with answer for common task better to use get-aduser. it's more agile

*dsquery guide https://shellgeek.com/dsget-user/